# How do I make the eth0 network interface persistent?

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

After configuring `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` to use the eth0 name I have successfully configured the `etc/network/interfaces` file with settings for eth0. When I reboot, however only the lo interface is showing.

I manually created the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file as such:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:8f:54:d7", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

Still when I reboot the eth0 interface is unavailable. I have to manually start it by using ifup command.

Can anyone help with this? FYI this is a virtual vm using esxi vmnext3 virtual nic if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.....in the /etc/network/interfaces file I had the auto line messed up.

Fixed that and all is good.

auto eth0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what you did. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)